# Complex Excel IF/THEN Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an IF statement to populate the "Invoice Status" column to either CURRENT, OVERDUE, or PAID based on multiple criteria.

Criteria 1: If there is an outstanding balance and the due date is over 30 days old, then the invoice status needs to state OVERDUE; but also,

Criteria 2: If there is an outstanding balance and the due date is in the future, the the invoice status needs to state CURRENT; but also,

Criteria 3: If there is NO outstanding balance, then the invoice needs to state PAID. End.

Here is my current formula that IS NOT working:

```
=IF(OR([@[Outstanding Balance]]>"0",CurrentDate-[@[Due Date]]>=1),"OVERDUE",
 IF(OR([@[Outstanding Balance]]>"0",[@[Due Date]]>=CurrentDate),"CURRENT",
 IF([@[Outstanding Balance]]="0","PAID","")))
```

[image]

Comment: and *"that IS NOT working"* means exactly what? Wrong result? Error in the Formula?

Comment: I think you want to change all the `OR` for `AND`

Comment: When I change all the OR to AND, the result shows FALSE instead of CURRENT, PAID, or OVERDUE.

Comment: "That IS NOT working" means that the return value is not what it is supposed to be based on the criteria.

Comment: `=IF([@[Outstanding Balance]]=0,"PAID",IF([@[Due Date]]<CurrentDate,"OVERDUE","CURRENT"))` EDITED to remove the `""` around the `0`

Comment: you also will want to remove the `""` around `0` in your formula to make it work.  You are comparing a number to a string and they are not equal.

Comment: Do each condition separately and once they work THEN combine them.

Comment: Omigosh! Thank you! I WAY over-complicated that. I appreciate all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with before reading the comments.

`=IF(AND([@[Outstanding Balance]]>0,CurrentDate[Current Date]-[@[Due Date]]>0),"OVERDUE",IF(AND([@[Outstanding Balance]]>0,CurrentDate[Current Date]-[@[Due Date]]<=0),"CURRENT",IF([@[Outstanding Balance]]=0,"PAID","")))`

Like @Scott Craner said "Remove the `""` around your `0`

I like his final formula better than mine.

@Scott Craner would you be willing to post your final formula as an answer to take your due?